# What is PSR in php ? Please explain with example

Tags: magento2, php-7, psr

How PSR is useful in Magento 2 .

I learned

```
PSR-0 – Autoloader Standard
PSR-1 – Basic Coding Standard
PSR-2 – Coding Style Guide
PSR-3 – Logger Interface
PSR-4- Autoloader Standard
```

but I want to learn from example .
can anyone show me examples .

Answer (score 6):

PSR stands for **PHP Standards Recommendations**, this is a code convention. Magento 2 uses [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) See https://www.php-fig.org/psr/ for the conventions and examples.

An example is that you should write methods in camelCase and not with underscores, for example:

```
public function my_method()
{
    // do something
}
```

Should be:

```
public function myMethod()
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: can you show examples .

Comment: @JaykumarR Added an example for you